# Black frame around 1080p screen

Tags: display, pi-3

I purchased several Raspberry Pi 3s, reading the spec that their max resolution was 1920x1080.

I purchased several HP 22uh monitors to go with these, knowing their max resolution matches this.

On fully setting up my Pi, there is a 3/4" black frame around the border of the screen. For the parts displayed, the image is sharp, however I would like to use the full screen as the current display looks dumb.

I played around with the Pi and the monitor, and cannot find what settings adjustments will fix this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried changing the aspect ratio? There are also settings in the config.txt file that will fix this.

Comment: Where is the config.txt file? Sorry, new to Pis

Comment: it is on boot partition

Comment: Assuming you are running Raspbian you can tun sudo raspi-config under advanced options is an overscan setting.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @SteveRobillard, that was spot on.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your `/boot/config.txt` file try changing `disable_overscan=1` and see what that does for the borders. If that does not help, leave `disable_overscan=1` and then try changing these values as well.

```
overscan_left=20
overscan_right=20
Overscan_top=20
Overscan_bottom=20
```

It will take some trial and error to find the correct values because the correct values are monitor specific.

Answer (score 2):

Use negative values as described in the info in `config.txt` file

This worked for me

```
disable_overscan=1

overscan_left=-16
overscan_right=-16
Overscan_top=-16
Overscan_bottom=-16
```

Answer (score 2):

For Raspberry PI 4 B and Ubuntu 19.10, if you have black borders above and below:

`vi /boot/firmware/usercfg.txt`

Add the following line:
`disable_overscan=1`

Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I was also having the same problem at the beginning. I tried various methods and failed. I got a solution after I made a change in display settings. it worked for me.

check this article. https://www.hackerstec.com/raspberry-pi-display-black-border-troubleshooting/
follow this article it has a method that is not available in forums 
It has a tutorial on how to change screen settings and remove black border